# How to search/fetch Google play store or iTunes store via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, itunes-store

How to search/fetch Google play store or iTunes store via API. Are there any gems which will allow you to search by name or category or allows you to fetch details by an id for the above stores using a gem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ITunesSerachAPI](https://github.com/rlivsey/itunes-search-api) but have yet have to find something for Android.